# Find the number of squares of a given image

Tags: probability

There is a $9\times 9$ square created by $10$ horizontal and vertical lines. Then a $3\times 3$ smaller square inside is removed as the image shows. Calculate the number of square formed out of lines.

I just calculated the number of possible squares before removing the $3\times 3$ square, which are $285$ possible ones. But I have no idea about calculating how much square disappeared after that except counting them one by one.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m29Rn.jpg)

Comment: Is a square "around" the empty $3\text{x}3$ considered as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, to count the total number of squares in the original $9\times9$ grid, we recognize that there are $9\cdot9 = 81$ $1\times1$ squares, $8\cdot8 = 64$  $2\times2$ squares, and so on. So the total number of squares is $9\cdot 9 + 8\cdot 8 + \dots + 1\cdot 1 = 285$ (as you correctly calculated). Now, I assume that we also include squares that "include" the empty $3\times3$ square, and only take away squares where bits of the edges are removed. We see that there vanishes $3\cdot3 = 9$ $1\times1$ squares, and $4\cdot4 = 16$ $2\times2$ squares, where we're really counting how many $n\times n$ squares fit inside a $(n+2) \times (n+2)$ square. $n = 3 \implies$ $5\cdot5 = 25$ squares. However, $n = 4$ is a problem since the left edge is "too close" to fit all the "problematic" $4\times4$ squares as we did for $n = 1, 2, 3$. $n=4$ instead asks how many $4\times4$ squares sit inside a $5\times6$ grid, which is $5\cdot6 = 30$. Notice how we for $n \ge 5$ can fit $0$ squares that aren't interrupted by the empty $3\times3$, since the maximum distance from any edge to the $3\times3$ is $4 < 5$. Hence, the total number of squares we count is: $285 - (9+16+25+30+5\cdot5 + 4\cdot4 + 3\cdot3 + 2\cdot2 + 1\cdot1) = 285 - 135 = \textbf{150}$ **squares**.